# How to create a ParcelFileDescriptor from a native file descriptor?

Tags: java, android

Need to unzip a zip file which is referred by a native file descriptor in an Android app.

Somehow, ParcelFileDescriptor.FromFd(int nativeFd) throws NullPointerException: FileDescriptor must not be null.

How to access the file referred by a native file descriptor on Android?

Tested the following code snippet in a unit test.

```
private static final Path TEST_DATA_DIR = "/path/to/test/";
Path zipFilePath = TEST_DATA_DIR.resolve("test.zip");
File zipFile = new File(zipFilePath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(zipFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
ParcelFileDescriptor newFd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromFd(fileDescriptor.getFd());
```

Expect the last line does not throw any exception, but it throws NullPointerException: FileDescriptor must not be null.